# Activity Logging in MicroStrategy

Tags: logging, android-activity, documentation, microstrategy

I need a documentation link for Microstrategy Activity logins. I have configured the project to log all Activities. But I can not get any specific Attributes and metrics inside the schema objects by using which I can create the Activity Report.

Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Schema Objects there are many objects like UserID and SessionID Attributes, please use this objects and also Project Session ID and Project ID which can give you Activity Logging information.

Comment: I dont know any official link for  microstrategy documentation. but you can refer official website .